# How should I give file path in windows?

Tags: java, file, classpath, filereader, netbeans-6.9

```
    String fileName = ":D/temp.txt";
    FileReader fileReader= new FileReader(fileName);
```

My file is in D partion.I want to give my text document path.I'm not known much about absolute and relative path.Please help to solve above file name path correct.
Other question is how should I change fileName when my temp file in same package in netbeans?

Answer (score 1):

```
String fileName = "D:\\temp.txt";
```